# Python: copy svg string to "image/svg+xml" format in windows clipboard, so can paste it as an svg image

Tags: python, string, svg, mime

Say I have the xml contents of an svg file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Created with matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) -->
<svg height="344.88pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 460.8 344.88" width="460.8pt" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
...
```

My question is, how to copy this string to windows clipboard, not as string, but as "image/svg+xml" data type, which can be pasted into powerpoint as an svg image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only clipboard library that I know of that supports Mime types is the QtClipboard: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QClipboard.html

You might want to take a look at it.

Possibly among the Mime Types you can set with `setMimeData` there is also **image/svg+xml**

Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
d = QtCore.QMimeData()
print(d.formats())  # Now it is an empty list "[]" because you still didn't set the data and the mime type

# Set data in the object with the required mime type
d.setData("image/svg+xml", b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><!-- Created with matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) --><svg height="344.88pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 460.8 344.88" width="460.8pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">')

print(d.formats())  # Now it prints: ['image/svg+xml']
```

From here you can take it to QClipboard.

I quote the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html

> The setMimeData() function is the ultimate in flexibility: it allows
>   you to add any QMimeData into the clipboard.

Comment: Could you elaborate on " there is also image/svg+xml"?

Comment: @Alex I said **possibly**, I am not sure it is among the supported Mime Types.

Comment: I'm probably out of luck in QtClipboard. It can only take `image` as is created by `QImage`. Other types don't work either, e.g. `text`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am not sure of what you did but I just tried and it works. I will edit the answer with an example.

Comment: @Alex also as you can see in the documentation, QClipboard is not only for images. http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I had some misunderstanding as for how windows clipboard MIME data types work. So they are simply byte stream with a 'description' such as "image/svg+xml"?

Comment: @Alex yes exactly, that's what a Mime Type is: just a description of the data. And the object MimeData is just a wrapper arount a byte stream and a string description (Mime Type)

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do the same thing on mac osx?

Comment: It should work exactly the same way on MacOS. Qt is cross platform, so it should work.

Comment: Also meaning the mac osx clipboard supports MIME data the same way as Windows  does?

Comment: I didn’t try, but I suppose it does.

Comment: A bit off-topic: have you installed PyQt on mac osx? There's a bunch of different tutorials online, which one did you use?

Comment: I tried it on macOS but so far no luck. The QMimeData part works. Can check `d.data('image/svg+xml')` and can see the content as `b'<?xml version="1...`. But, after `QApplication.clipboard().setMimeData(d)`, the macOS clipboard says `clipboard contents: unknown`. Can't paste to powerpoint either. Any idea why?

Comment: Nope, at this point I am not sure anymore... maybe MacOS does not support that mime type...